# Как заставить Eclipse увидеть новую версию Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, сервер, eclipse, tomcat

Пытаюсь подружить сервер Tomcat со средой выполнения Eclipse. Она "видит" версию сервера до 7-й включительно (см. изображение), хотя я скачал 9-ю. Переходя на следующий шаг диалогового окна (кнопка Next), я ожидаемо получаю ошибку: программа говорит мне, что хочет получить путь до Tomcat 7-й версии, а я даю ей ссылку на папку с девятой версией.

Пытаясь решить проблему, установил JST Server Adapters из меню Help -> Install New Software. Там же скачал инструментарий web-разработки, но всё одно.

Как быть?

У меня версия Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16.0) и ОС Windows 10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась обновлением версии программы. Через меню Help -> Check for Updates обновил предлагавшиеся модули и, собственно, версия программы стала более высокой - Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21.0).

Теперь "просматриваются" Apache Tomcat вплоть до 10-й версии